# How to tell tags and fields in simple and straight SELECT statement in CnosDB?

Tags: database, cnosdb

In CnosDB, tags and fields are basically two different set of columns. The former are indexed while the latter are not. Tags can be "group by" while fields cannot. Hence, writing a SELECT statement is tricky because you gotta be careful with these "columns"

However, it is not intuitive to find out who the tags and fields are in simple and straight [SELECT statement](https://cnosdb.github.io/docs/content/cnosdb/latest/cnosql/cnosql_syntax.html). For example:

```
> select * from air
name: air
time                 pressure station     temperature visibility
----                 -------- -------     ----------- ----------
2021-08-31T16:00:00Z 78       LianYunGang 63          71
2021-08-31T16:00:00Z 75       XiaoMaiDao  79          68
```

In the above case, station is the tag, pressure\temperature\visibility are fields. They are neither ordered by timestamp, tags, fields, or denoted by some display.

Are there any simpler ways to tell the tags and fields then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these commands in CnosDB CLI to tell the tags and fields.

First of all, you need to use the command `USE <databasename>` to specify a database.

Then, you can use the command as follows:

- `SHOW MEASUREMENTS` to see all the measurements in the database.
- `SHOW TAG KEYS` to see all the tags in the database.
- `SHOW FIELD KEYS` to see all the fileds in the database.
- `SHOW SERIES` to see all the series in the database.

Click [here](https://www.cnosdb.com/content/cnosdb/latest/cnosql/cnosql_management.html) for more information.

Comment: But can we just write simpler queries like "select * from air" and then see the tags, fields in different format, instead of running above queries one by one?